# How to return more than one value from a function in Julia?

Tags: julia

For the following function in Julia, I want to return both, the circumference and area of a rectangle given it’s length and breadth in centimeter.

```
function rectangle(length, breadth)
           circumference = 2(length + breadth)
           area = length*breadth
       end
```

However on executing `rectangle(3, 4)` it returns only one value (the **area**).

```
julia> rectangle(3, 4)
12
```

Answer (score 1):

For returning more than one value from a function, use a tuple.

```
julia> function rectangle(length, breadth)
           circumference = 2(length + breadth)
           area = length*breadth
           return circumference, area
       end
rectangle (generic function with 1 method)
julia> rectangle(3, 4)
(14, 12)
```

More information on **tuples** can be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Tuples-1

Comment: You can remove the parenthesis around the return values, they serve no purpose.

Comment: I personally feel the code is more readable when you have the parenthesis near `return`. Instead of that I like skipping the `return` keyword because it is not needed when located at the end of the function. Does anyone know are there any language style guidelines for that? It is not described in the main style guide:  https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/index.html